# How can I change the indexes in field?

Tags: java, field

I have a field a[] inside is 1, 5, 3, 2, 4
when i reach number 3 in for loop i want to send it(number 3) to the end of field so it will have index 4 and indexes of other numbers (2 and 4) have to be one less `a[2] = 2, a[3] = 4`

How can i do that? It can be a field with for example 100 values in.
Thanks for the reply!

My program look like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if(a[i] == 3) {
        // i dont know what have to go there
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have to use an `Array` or can we utilize an `ArrayList` in the solution?

Comment: One solution would be to use `System.arraycopy` to move all the numbers along one place, and then set `a[a.length - 1] = 3`. I agree with gonzo that a `List` is much better for this. With a `List` you don't even need a loop. Just do `list.remove((Integer) 3); list.add(3);`.

Answer (score 1):

```
int match = 3;
for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if(a[i] == match) {
       a[i] = a[i+1];
       a[i+1] = a[i+2];
       a[i+2] = match;
    }
}
```

Note that there is ZERO error checking

[edit] With some safety (no 'need' for error checking in this version as I just move the entire array one position to the left and put the match variable at the end.

```
int match = 3;
for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if(a[i] == match) {
       for int j = i; j < a.length-1; j++) {
          a[j] = a[j+1];
       }
       a[j] = match;
       break;
    }

    }
}
```

[/edit]